# Identifying significant gaps in timeline

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, outliers

Someone tossed me the following question. Say, you have medical records for many patients recovering from the same/similar injury. If you take a look at one medical record, you might see various medical visits on various days. On this timeline, you may also see a gap in treatment. How do you tell if that gap in treatment is significant for this person, at this point in time?

### Backgound

There is an assumption, that gaps in treatment may be okay for some medical provider types towards the end of treatment period; but this is not okay early on.

Here is an example of what a medical timeline may look like,

[image: Example of treatment timeline]

### Question

The red oval indicates a *potential* gap in treatment. How is this statistically validated as an outlier (or not)?

### Code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


days = np.arange(0, 50)
days

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue']
medtypes = dict(zip(colors, ['Hosp', 'Chiro', 'Phys']))
for color, med in medtypes.items():
    visits = np.random.choice(days, replace=False, size=np.random.randint(low=3, high=10))
    y = np.ones(visits.shape[0])
    ax.scatter(x=visits, y=y, c=color, label=med,
               alpha=0.3, edgecolors='none', marker='x', s = 120)

ax.legend()
ax.grid(False)
ax.set_yticks([])
plt.xlabel('Day')
plt.ylabel('Visited')
plt.title('Medical Treatment Visits')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "significant for a person"?  This sounds like something for a doctor to opine about, not a statistician.

Comment: @whuber What I mean, is that, for a population with the same/similar diagnosis, treatment should have a certain pattern (e.g. an average rate of visits to the doctor, like a Poisson process). So, if this person waits much longer between medical visits, is there a way to flag this through some classifier/mechanism?